# IIS and ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT published app not using value in web.config?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-2.0

Im setting this value at the time I publish, via settings in the csproj file.  The resulting web.config has this

```
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\something-something.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="QA" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Yet, when I run the app on the target server, I get an error about this environment variable.  How can the variable still be set to "Development" ?

> ```
> <strong>The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications.</strong>
> It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users.
> For local debugging, enable the <strong>Development</strong> environment by setting the <strong>ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT</strong>
> ```
>
> environment variable to **Development**
>       and restarting the app.

[update]
What is also strange, is that not all of the application areas see this error.  I have 4 environments - Local, Test, QA and Prod
Test is my "dev" server, and publishing there I do not get an error related to this environment variable.

[ **update** ]
After pulling some hair out, I noticed I was also getting a http 500 error, however it was getting lost in the noise.  Looks like there is a data issue that lead to an exception in my code, but the notice about environment variable was a bit misleading.

Comment: Can you share your complete web.config file excluding sensitive information if there is any?

Comment: Updated, see above.  Correct me if im wrong, but this value controls what settings file is looked for in the root of the app, eg.  appsettings.QA.json, correct?

Comment: How are you running the app? Is it being run in an App Pool in IIS, or are you running it another way? (`dotnet MyApp.dll`) for example. The Web.config is only used by IIS. Also, what hosting model are you using? In proc or out of proc? I believe the Web.config environment variables only work with in proc.

Comment: There are two different apps on the same server, one I use for "dev", the other for "QA".  Each have their own app pool:  no managed code, Mananged Pipeline Mode = Integrated

Comment: I doubt its a config issue, but see original post